# Используются ли в современных веб-проектах Basic и Digest аутентификации?

Tags: авторизация, аутентификация

Я в них не сильно разбираюсь, поэтому мое мало информированное мнение пока стоит на позиции, что они почти никогда не пригодятся, и если нужно будет создавать легкий или средний веб-проект, то алгоритм аутентификации и авторизации пользователей и админов будет целиком на плечах веб-разработчика, и скорее всего так все делают?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, давайте разберемся как работают перечисленные вами механизмы аутентификации.

При [HTTP Basic](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#.D0.91.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B0.D1.83.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F) аутентификации вместе с *каждым* HTTP запросом вместе с заголовками передается связка логин/пароль, которые позволяют однозначно аутентифицировать пользователя.

[HTTP Digest](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) аутентификация похожа на HTTP Basic, но вместо связки логин/пароль передается контрольная сумма, вычисленная на основе параметров запроса (метода, URI, иногда тела запроса), логина, пароля и, возможно, еще нескольких дополнительных параметров. (Часто используется уникальный для каждого запроса параметр `nonce`, препятствующий выполнению атаки на повторение запросов.)

Если говорить о других типах аутентификации, то чаще всего web-приложения используют аутентификацию на базе [Cookie](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#.D0.90.D1.83.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D0.BE_Cookies). Пользователь передает логин/пароль на сервер, сервер проверяет эти данные и в случае успеха отдает пользователю заголовок `Set-Cookie` с идентификатором *пользовательского сеанса*. При всех последующих запросах пользователь передает посредством Cookie этот идентификатор, который и используется для аутентификации.

Принципиальная разница между первыми двумя методами и последним заключается в том, что для механизмов HTTP Basic и HTTP Digest серверу *не нужно хранить сессионные данные* пользователей (идентификатор пользовательской сессии). При таком подходе, каждый HTTP запрос содержит всю необходимую для построения ответа информацию и может быть изолирован от предыдущих/последующих запросов.

Идея сервера, не хранящего состояние пользовательских сессий лежит в основе довольно популярного [RESTful](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) подхода. Этот подход часто используется для построения серверного API.

И да, говорить, что HTTP Basic/Digest не используется в современных web-проектах -- неверно. Тут все зависит от сложности, целей и задач проекта.

**Замечание:**

Важно понимать разницу между *аутентификацией* и *авторизацией*.

Под *аутентификацией* обычно понимают процесс определения того, что пользователь является именно тем, кем он представился. Под *авторизацией* обычно понимают проверку полномочий конкретного, уже аутентифицированного, пользователя на выполнение некоторых действий в системе.

Выше были указаны только методы *аутентификации*. Построение правильного механизма *авторизации* пользователей все равно лежит на плечах разработчика.

Answer (score 1):

Для аутентификации непосредственно пользователей Basic и Digest аутентификация используются редко. Обычно после отправки логина/пароля и их валидации пользователю прописывают SESSIONID в cookies и в дальнейшем используют именно его. Однако при работе с клиентами API оба вида аутентификации достаточно широко используются. Тут можно либо просить клиента передавать Basic/Digest токен с каждым запросом, либо использовать Basic (реже Digest) аутентификацию для выдачи токена OAuth. При этом важно помнить, что использовать Basic аутентификацию на незашифрованном соединении нельзя, ведь логин и пароль передаются в открытом виде.